# Python module exists in terminal but not when run through PHP's shell_exec

Tags: php, python, macos, localhost

When i run a python script in terminal it works just fine. 
I then proceed to run the exact same script via PHP's shell_exec from localhost.

```
shell_exec("python /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pharm/Webmaps.py")
```

The error it gives is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pharm/Webmaps.py", line 1, in import folium ImportError: No module named folium
```

It doesn't recognize the modules that are installed. Needless to say that it works just fine from windows on localhost.

Comment: does your `python-packages` directory change between the working and non-working environments?

Comment: Compare `python -c "import site;print(site.getsitepackages())"` in your terminal with `shell_exec('python -c "import site;print(site.getsitepackages())"')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple versions of Python on your machine, this may not work. Essentially what I think is happening is that the version of Python that is being called when you use `shell_exec` is different from the one that you know `folium` is installed in. Try creating a file like below:

```
# test.py
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

and use `shell_exec("python /path/to/test.py")`. Then try `python /path/to/test.py`. I expect that it will be different. Even if it is not different, it still could mean that you have two or more Python installations that are the exact same versions (unlikely, but possible). You can run the following to check that. Try both `shell_exec("which python")` and `which python`. I'd venture a guess that that should give you enough information to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you install packages using `sudo pip install xxxxx` then it will be saved under `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/dist-packages`.
If you omit `sudo` it will be saved under user's home directory and most probably it will not be accessible via php engine.
So try to install packages adding the `sudo` command.